# Fetching & Updating Data Using ajax and Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I've been working on a forum based system. With the help of jquery, php, bootstrap, and such I could develop a forum in which a user can post, delete, and edit. I've defined an edit button for the person who sent the post, with click of a mouse, "modal" comes down, and some forms will appear for the user to enter in his/her desired info. I've been searching over internet for the right ajax method to collect the data from server first, and save the changes that user makes to it, but I was unsuccessful to define what i'm looking for. here below is the modal code,

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container">
                    <form style="width: 550px;" action="" method="post" role="form">
                        <div class="from-group">
                            <label for="title">Title: </label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="title" id="title" value="" placeholder="Page Title">
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="from-group">
                            <label for="label">Label: </label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="label" id="label" value="" placeholder="Page Label">
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="from-group">
                            <label for="header">Header: </label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="header" id="header" value="" placeholder="Page Header">
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="from-group">
                            <label for="body">Body: </label>
                            <textarea class="form-control editor" name="body" id="body" row="8" placeholder="Page Body"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <!-- <button style=" color:#FFFFFF; background-color: #4D6064"  type="submit" class="btn ">Submit</button> -->
                        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">
                        <br>
                        <br>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to show the jQuery/Javascript code you have attempted, not just the HTML.

Comment: I haven't attempted :), that's why I'm here dude, to get an idea

Comment: @Jessie Then you are at the wrong place :-)

Comment: Wrong place to get *ideas*. StackOverflow is about practical *code* problems and solutions. Sorry

Comment: okay, then I will remove the post, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'right' ajax method?

Ajax is just a way to communicate with a server.

What data do you want to collect?

A GET request will request that the server sends you back some 'data' in the response, its probably the very first example in any 'ajax'-wrapper library, for example, this snippet

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://fiddle.jshell.net/favicon.png",
  beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
    xhr.overrideMimeType( "text/plain; charset=x-user-defined" );
  }
})
  .done(function( data ) {
    if ( console && console.log ) {
      console.log( "Sample of data:", data.slice( 0, 100 ) );
    }
 });
```

is from jQuery.ajax http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

It sends a request to the url specified (ignore the beforeSend function, it does nothing outrageous anyway) and then handles the response in the '.done' handler. If you're not familiar with promises, just think of that '.done' handler as a callback that contains the data i.e. at some point in the future the server will respond (hopefully) with some data and that function handles it.

Comment: Well, i'm planning the fetch the data user sent to the forum earlier, this is helpful, will check on it :)

Comment: If you're using jQuery then go for it but dont add jQuery to your site just for ajax. Using the XmlHttpRequest object is pretty straight-forward and works in all browsers. Some more info on using it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest